# Axios data coming up as ImmutableMultiDict([]) when sent to Flask POST route, but work with Postman

Tags: reactjs, post, flask, axios, postman

I am using Flask to create a POST method to register a new user in my MySQL database. I tried created an Axios method to send the POST request from my React JS application. I was testing with Postman, and I am sending it using application/x-www-form-urlencoded. The registration works in Postman, but the data comes up as **ImmutableMultiDict([])**.

Flask code:

```
@app.route('/registerUser', methods=['POST'])
def registerUser():
    data = request.form
        if len(data) is 0:
            return 'Request was empty!'
        username = data['username']
        password = data['password']
        email = data['email']
        user = User(username=username, 
                    password=password, 
                    email=email)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        return 'Registration success!'
    return 'Registration failed!'
```

React code:

```
class Signup extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: '',
            email: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.clearInputs = this.clearInputs.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }
    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        const config = {
            headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }
        axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/registerUser`, 
            this.state, config)
             .then(res => {
                alert(res.data);
             })
             .catch((err) => {
                alert(err);
             });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className='signup'>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <label>
                        Username
                        <input type='text' name='username' 
                               value={this.state.username}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Password
                        <input type='password' name='password' 
                               value={this.state.password} 
                               onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        Email
                        <input type='text' name='email' 
                               value={this.state.email}
                               onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                    </label>
                    <input type='submit' value='Submit' /><br/>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Signup;
```

Why is the data not properly sending from Axios? I am using **CORS** in flask, and both Postman and Axios should be sending the same form data.

EDIT: I changed the POST request to use request.form
However, Postman works, but Axios still doesn't.
From Postman:

```
ImmutableMultiDict([('username', 'person'), ('password', 'Password1'), ('email', 'example@example.com')])
```

From Axios:  `ImmutableMultiDict([('{"username":"someone","password":"Password1","email":"email@example.com"}', '')])`

Is Axios misconfigured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. By default, Axios sends data by JSON format. In order to comply with urlencoded, you would need to build a new URLSearchParams object to send instead. See the [documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format)

This is the working React code:

```
handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    const config = {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }
    const getParams = (obj) => {
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        const keys = Object.keys(obj);
        for(let k of keys){
            params.append(k, obj[k]);
        }
        return params;
    }
    axios.post(`http://localhost:5000/registerUser`, 
        getParams(this.state), config)
         .then(res => {
            alert(res.data);
            this.clearInputs();
         })
         .catch((err) => {
            alert(err);
         });
}
```

This works with my OP Flask code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to *coerce the request data into type `JSON`* within your `registerUser` route since you're trying to access a JSON response but you sent the request over in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format. `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the `default` form content type specification created by the [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4) and is usually used to send text/ASCII data. Maybe you could try the following and see if you get the expected `JSON` response:

```
app.route('/registerUser', methods=['POST'])
def registerUser():
    requestJson = request.get_json(force=True)

    # check that requestJson is correct if so
    # create and save your new user to your db

    return 'Registration failed!'
```

If your `requestJson` is as expected then you can just pull out the required fields and save your new user to your database. If not please print out the request you're receiving to see how it can be appropriately parsed.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: It does help. I used form data from Postman and it works, however, see my edit for the new bug. Axios is sending the obj object and it's returning an imperfect JSON object.

Comment: what does request.form.keys()[0] print out? I'm going to assume: {"obj":{"username":"uernmf","password":"Password12!","email":"k@ao.com"}}'

Comment: I get:
TypeError: 'dict_keyiterator' object is not subscriptable

Comment: See my new edit. What is confusing me is how I am telling Axios to send urlencoded, but it is clearly JSON data. I do not want to change the Flask code to use JSON because this would defeat the purpose.

Comment: ok so you're using request.form now. Can you print request.form[0] and paste that in? It should remove the array and return the tuple back

Comment: I figured out the issue. See my post below. Thank you for your help though!